# what does " 'true' as QUERYID " mean?

Tags: mysql, mybatis

This is one sql in mybatis mapper.xml:
select 'true' as QUERYID, id, name, parent_id, level, status,...
I want to know the mean of " 'true' as QUERYID ".
Thanks.

Comment: That means the query is getting a column `QueryID` in the result "table", whose value is always string 'true'

Comment: Maybe I get it~  In fact, this code is created by a tool named mybatis-generater. And " QUERYID " is not in my model entity. I don't know why the tool create " QUERYID " column.

Comment: @Tiki-Taka In your `<table>` element, you have either `selectByExampleQueryId` or `selectByPrimaryKeyQueryId` set as true. Hence the value will be added to the select list of the select by primary key statement in this form: '<value>' as QUERYID". This can be useful for identifying queries in DBA tracing tools at run time. If you use thus value, you should specify a unique id for every different query generated by Abator.

Comment: @RahulSharma Oh, Indeed so. thanks for you.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically to your question, in query: `select 'true' as QUERYID, id, name, parent_id, level, status,...`

The `select true` will select a row with a single `1` if there's a match, and no row at all if there is no match.

And the `QUERYID` means that in your `<table>` element, you have either `selectByExampleQueryId` or `selectByPrimaryKeyQueryId` set as true. Hence the value will be added to the select list of the select by primary key statement in this form: `<value>` as QUERYID". This can be useful for identifying queries in DBA tracing tools at run time. If you use thus value, you should specify a unique id for every different query generated by Abator

Answer (score -1):

> Retrieves the query stored in the specified Salesforce record,
>   executes the query and Makes the query results available through a
>   dataset as seen on the Template Builder window.

Comment: Why downgrade the answer, please let me know  what is correct answer if any other?